# Is $U$ an open ball?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $f,g: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and $f(t)<g(t)$ for all $t\in [0,1]$. Consider the set $$U = \{h\in C[0,1] : f(t)<h(t)< g(t), \ \forall t \in  [0,1]\}$$ in the space $X= (C[0,1], ||\ ||_\infty)$. Is $U$ a ball in $X$? If not, what condition of $f,g$  will ensure that $U$ is an open ball?

$||\ ||_\infty$ is the sup metric induced by the norm.

Is $U$ open in $X$?  I know that open ball is open set. So, if I can prove $U$ is an open ball then $U$ is also an open set.

But I have no idea how to prove $U$ is a ball. Please help.

Comment: Not all open sets are open balls. The problem seems to ask whether or not it is open. You seen to think it is open. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$U$ is indeed open as for any $h$ is $U$, we can find an open ball for the norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert_\infty$ centered on $h$ included in $U$. This follows from the fact that continuous maps on a compact set attains their minimum and maximum.

Then, $U$ is an open ball if and only if $g-f$ is constant. If $g-f$ is constant equal to $a$ then $U= B\left(\frac{f+g}{2},a/2\right)$. And prove that $U$ can’t be an open ball if $g-f$ is not constant.